# After moving my facebook php from localhost to web server, it stops working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I'm having trouble making a simple FB app.

I developed it on localhost and it worked perfectly. The whole idea is to have a desktop app which launches a facebook login page with a return url. Once the user succesfully logs in, he is sent to that return url to display a message that says "Thanks for logging".

When I try it on localhost (by setting my app domain and Site url on facebook to localhost) it works flawlessly. But now that I moved the php to a webserver, my $user var never gets populated. (Yes, I updated the app domain and return url on facebook to point to my domain.)

I started investigating and tracked down what I think could be the error. On the base_facebook.php there's this **getUserFromAvailableData()** method with the following portion of code: (The echos are mine btw)

```
$access_token = $this->getAccessToken();

echo "Access Token: ".$access_token."<br/>";
echo $this->getApplicationAccessToken()."<br/>";

if ($access_token && $access_token != $this->getApplicationAccessToken() && !($user && $persisted_access_token == $access_token)) {

  echo "This doesn't get printed at all.";
  $user = $this->getUserFromAccessToken();
  if ($user) {
        $this->setPersistentData('user_id', $user);
  } else {
        $this->clearAllPersistentData();
  }
}

return $user;
```

As you can see, there's a echo that never gets printed and I managed to find out that getAccessToken and getApplicationAccessToken return the exact same string, which is why my $user comes empty.

So my question would be: Why does this work on localhost but not on my webserver? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume that you have set your config local and not in your live stage.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña what do you mean? The php's are currently on a dev server, but I can't get it to work yet. On localhost it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Not the PHP configuration, I am not yet familiar with the API but double check the important configuration especially those with paths that you used in the system. If this requires for your tokens to work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your code in a real server you need to make a Facebook application with your domain name that you will use it to host tour php script and put your Application Id and your App Secret :

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$config['secret'] = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks @mrmm , but I already have done all that. My application is working, it connects to fb, I get the user token and everything. The problem is that all of this works good when developing on localhost, but when I upload it to my webserver and change my facebook app's domain to match the new domain and everything, It's stops working.

Comment: @PituSeligmann I am also have the same problem. What i need to do for this problem?.